# Spring Boot WRo4j Need to restart app to see javascript changes

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, wro4j

I'm using Spring boot and Wro4j. The problem we're having is every time we do a change on our of js files, we need to restart our application. is there anyway to avoid this?

here's our wro.properties.

```
#List of preProcessors
preProcessors=lessCssImport
#List of postProcessors
postProcessors=less4j,jsMin
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration options:

```
resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod=5
```

This option is an int value for specifying how often (in seconds) the resource changes should be checked. When this value is 0, the cache is never refreshed. When a resource change is detected, the cached group containing changed resource will be invalidated. This is useful during development, when resources are changed often.

```
resourceWatcherAsync=true
```

This is a boolean which enables/disables asynchronous resource watcher. The true value does make sense when resourceWatcherUpdatePeriod is greater than 0.

More configuration options can be found [here](http://wro4j.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ConfigurationOptions/).